# league/flysystem - RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/proc/tty/driver): failed to open dir: Permission denied

Tags: php, flysystem

Is it possible to avoid this exception (maybe by excluding directories which can't be read by the PHP process because of a lack of permissions?). I can't find it in the docs.

```
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/proc/tty/driver): 
failed to open dir: Permission denied
```

My code:

```
$filesystem = new Filesystem(new Local('/proc', LOCK_EX, Local::SKIP_LINKS));
$filesystem->listContents('.', true);
```

Comment: Instead of trying to work around this in PHP, I recommend figuring out why the permissions are incorrect. Also, Flysystem's goal is to provide a filesystem abstraction for storage. It seems you're trying to do something that will only ever be local. I recommend not using Flysystem for this, it's just not the tool for that job it seems.

Comment: @FrankdeJonge I see, so your library is meant for the web (where we usually can control file permissions) and not for directories like /proc. For me that is the answer to my question. Thank you!

Comment: The /proc directories have tightened permissions which conflict with how PHP handles operations in some cases. Per linux distribution there's a group like wheel or admin or root which owns those directories and you can mostly only read them. However some read operations like listing contents require more than read permissions. This is the same for web and non-web, although in web situations you're more likely to have correct permissions. So the solution is to figure out how to get the right permissions for these operations.

Comment: @FrankdeJonge Thank you very much for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

See: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/831 its essentially the same issue.

To do the workaround you would need to extend the class and overwrite the method [`getRecursiveDirectoryIterator`](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/master/src/Adapter/Local.php#L458), as there is no way to change the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` modes.

Change the default mode to `RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD` which will not fail when it attempts to open.

**For example:**

```
<?php
class LocalSkipError extends Local {
    protected function getRecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, $mode = RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD)
    {
        return new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
            $mode
        );
    }
}

$filesystem = new Filesystem(new LocalSkipError('/proc', LOCK_EX, Local::SKIP_LINKS));
$filesystem->listContents('.', true);
```

But its not recommended:

- https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/880#issuecomment-355762763
- https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/831#issuecomment-329504331

Comment: expect `final` to be added in future versions ;p